# how to access the array elements using a variable without using map

Tags: reactjs, rest

I was working on reactjs project. i was able to access the elements of array using map, but i want to access a particular element of the array only, not all. I don't know how to access the array elements using a variable without using map. Can anyone help me?

```
this.state.ad.map(object => <tr>
                                        <td>{object.RRF_ID}</td>
                                        <td>{object.DELTA_HIGH}</td>
                                        <td>{object.DELTA_IND}</td>
                                        </tr>)
```

Comment: The question is not clear, can you elaborate?

Comment: You mean with for loop?

Comment: Just a particular array element.@richardnelson

Comment: Then like this: this.state.ad[1].RRF_ID.

Comment: Probably he is looking for some `find` query in an array

Answer (score 0):

```
var admin = this.state.collabs.find(function (element) {
  if (element.isAdmin) {
    return element.userId
  }
});
```

collabs is an array and i tried to find only that element whose isAdmin is true and that element will assign to admin variable,this example may help you